# What Sprachgesetze are suggested by Quantitative Linguistics on semantic level?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics, quantitative-linguistics

Sprachgesetze, verbatimally laws of language, are stochastic statements about features of a language based on empirical evaluation of a corpus.

The Sprachgesetze I found are mainly quantitative statements about features on syntactic (piotrowki-law) or lexical level. Do you know of any Sprachgesetz concerning semantics?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this term. Is it something like a conversational maxim?

Comment: I find quite a few unusual terms in this question. Which one are you asking about @curiousdannii?

Comment: "Sprachgesetze" was the main one. But yes there are lots of other obscure words. And confusingly [its German Wikipedia page](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachgesetz) and [its linked English Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_rights) seem to be about completely different things.

Comment: there is "law of quantitative linguistics", but i do not know if it is a fixed term in english language.

Comment: @meireikei Please [edit] this to define the terms you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There are some laws concerning polysemy. Please look at: http://lql.uni-trier.de/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: We don't allow answers that are little more than links. Please [edit] this to summarise that page for us. :)